# How to remove default shadow in ListItemPresenter in android TV

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-tv, leanback

how to remove the default black shadow (black shadow or each corners) in `ListItemPresenter`,
attaching image of presenter view

[image]

here is `xml` of the item presenter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/block_bg_state"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ...


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using `ListRowPresenter`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a shadow, then you don't need to use a CardView. It's meant as a "wrapper" to add elevation (a shadow) and rounded corners to the view it holds.

If this is your complete layout, you can also remove the LinearLayout and add the layout width/height directly to your ConstraintLayout.